# Calculating number of validators on dune

Tags: sql, ethereum, ether, dune, staking

to find total validators on eth , i am using below logics :

```
SELECT sum(amount_staked) FROM staking_ethereum.deposits as a,
SELECT sum(amount)/1e9 FROM ethereum.withdrawals as b
```

and my output is `(a-b)/32` , am i making a mistake ?

I saw some query where hildobby did

```
CASE WHEN amount/1e9 BETWEEN 20 AND 32 THEN amount/1e9
     WHEN amount/1e9 > 32 THEN 32
END AS amount_full_withdrawn
```

so instead of subtracting amount I calculated above, he subtracted `amount_full_withdrawn`
But I am unable to understand this logic.